# How to get changed lines only in diff in TortoiseGit or with Windows?

Tags: windows, git, tortoisegit

I have two (big) files and what I need is to extract changed/added lines only. Is a plain text file (CSV).

Simply return and save a third file with these lines..

**UPDATE**

I resolved with DiffMerge using the "Show Differences Only" function built in described [here](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/webhelp/sec__file__displaymode.html).

By the way, I still require a solution that "programmatically" do the same thing but I will create another Question maybe because I need it in a Linux environment.

**UPDATE 2**

Resolved also with TortoiseGit, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select two files, and TortoiseGit -> Diff

[image]

2. Create Patch file in TortoiseGitMerge

[image]

3. the unified diff file

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

For viewing diff only, using "Collapse".

[image]

---

**UPDATE 2**

If you don't need the context, just set the "Context lines for patches" to zero.

[image]

Comment: the result unfortunately is not OK for me but I resolved "manually" with DiffMerge for Windows

Comment: If you need some automation of TortoiseGitMerge, please fire an issue on [TortoiseGit on GitLab](https://tortoisegit.org/issues)

Answer (score 0):

```
diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' file1 file2
```

Comment: I'm in Windows:
'diff' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Maybe I have to add a PATH in the system environment?

Comment: Try
FC file1 file2
in windows

Comment: Bad output, it works but shows only the changed line part and grouped per change set...

Comment: sorry, could not really test the windows approach being a ubuntu user

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for could be as simple as the default unified diff format given by `git diff` but with context lines stripped. You will still get the location information before every change.

```
git diff --unified=0 <commit1>:<path/to/file1> <commit2>:<path/to/file2> > <output file>
```

The files do not have to be versioned under Git, you can just omit the commit reference in that case (or when comparing separate files in same version). For different versions of the same file

```
git diff --unified=0 <commit1> <commit2> -- <file> > <output file>
```

Comment: the result is exactly like the @Yue Lin Ho solution but unfortunately is not OK for me but I resolved "manually" with DiffMerge for Windows